# Flexbox: each element 1/3 width, fall under each other if not enough space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am looking for a way (with Flexbox, not Grid) to create a layout, when I have a container with `x` cards inside, and each card inside should take 1/3 of the container width. So cards number 1,2,3 will be in the first row, cards number 4,5... in the second row etc.
I feel like it is impossible with flexbox, I don't wanna do some checks for number of items, I used `map` to map cards in containers of max 3 cards but I didn't like the solution. Before I move to using grid, I would love to get some insight if it is possible to acomplish with Flexbox.
The code is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the CSS you tried please. And have you tried setting the card to 33% width with flex-wrap set to wrap?

Comment: What should be the width of last 2 cards? 50% or 33%?

Answer (score 2):

you should set `box-sizing: border-box;` on the cards so padding and borders are calculated in their width. and set their `max-width: 33.33%`.

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: orange;
}

.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference will be for the second row. There are two options for the last two element width.

**Option 1** Last two nodes take 33% width only and leave the right side blank.

You have to use `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` for `.container` and `display: flex; flex: 0 1 33%;` for the child element, which is `.card`.. Here `flex-shrink` is to be set for child

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 33%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
</div>
```

**Option 2** Last two element use 50% width each.
You have to use `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` for container and `display: flex; flex: 1 0 33%;` to the child element, which is `.card`. Here `flex-grow` is to be set for child

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Flex-wrap can help you with that

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card{
  min-width: 33.3333%;
}
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/jriches/pen/WNjVaav

Comment: will not work as intended as `min-width` will make it aleast that width. Mean, if the content is big enough, they layout will be easily broken as the width can be larger then 33.33%.

Answer (score -3):

Use 33.33333333% width in your card class.

Comment: `33.33%` is more then enough. Betetr yet would be: `calc(1/3)`. However this will not work as intended as it misses 2 fundemental things: `box-sizing: border-box;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;`